# How do I open a file from a prompt with VS Code and go to a specific line number?

Tags: command-line, editor, visual-studio-code

I want to integrate Visual Studio Code with some of my other tools, and part of that is being able to launch Visual Studio Code passing a file name, line number, and column number, to position the cursor at a specific place in the file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Passing in line/column information along with the file name is currently not supported but sounds like a good feature request. Can you share the format that your tool is expecting?

Also, would you expect the file to open in a new instance or in the last active instance?

Comment: @BenjaminPasero I would be happy with `--line 25 --column 40` (or `-l:25 -c:40`). I would want them to load in the last active instance, but there may be cases where this is not desirable. Specifying a new instance via the OS, or allowed launching with named instances would be nice to have. E.g., I might have a named instance called Ad Hoc that would spin up if it does not already exist. This would get used for random files that I edit that are not part of regular projects.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a generaly accepted way of doing it. E.g. I know that some common pattern is filename:<line>:<column>. With this it could all go into one line instead of having to add more arguments.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero There are many standards :) I normally follow the [GNU Argument Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html) - ignore my incorrect syntax above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the new 0.5.0 release you can open one ore multiple files on a line and column using the following syntax:

```
code -g file1:<line>:<column?> file2:<line>:<column?> file3:<line>:<column?>
```

Comment: In Windows 10 using code v1.5.3, I get the following error: `Arguments in '--goto' mode should be in the format of 'FILE(:LINE(:COLUMN))'` when I do `code -g c:\tmp\new.txt:1:1`. The file exists. Testing further, I found that `code c:\tmp\new.txt:1:1` opens an `Untitled-1` file instead. `code c:\tmp\new.txt` opens the file correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like we have a bug there, good catch. It seems though we fixed it in our nightly builds. You can give our preview releases a try from: http://code.visualstudio.com/Download#insiders

Comment: Has this fix been released yet @BenjaminPasero? I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Yes, otherwise please file a bug.